# Wpf Button Control Template

Tags: wpf

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHXMR.jpg)

I need Button Control Template as shown in the image.So can anyone help me to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code in your app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Source="DHXMR.jpg"  />
                       <ContentControl  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

will turn out to show buttons like that:

[image]

Of course you need to remove the white "Button" text from the sample image you provided in your link - but I guess you're able to do that on your own

Comment: If the answer was useful for you, I would appreciate if you accept it by the clicking the "tick"